# How to show product custom attribute next to product in product detail page in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I want to show product custom attribute next to product in product detail page in magento2.2.5?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have just added custom attribute from backend. But magento2 default shows custom attribute under details..But that also not showing in pdp page

Comment: what is attribute code and where you want to show ? could you please add a snapshot ?

Comment: I want to show below the add to cart button in Product detail page. My attribute code is white_gold and rose_gold.

Comment: I have shared the screenshot. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `catalog_product_view.xml` at:

> Mage2Root/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="gold" template="Magento_Catalog::gold.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Now create `gold.phtml` at:

> Mage2Root/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/gold.phtml

with following code:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php //echo $_product->getName(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getWhiteGold(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getRoseGold(); ?>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: Welcome Amy, glad to know :)